# Javascript Form Validation- can't validate one variable?

Tags: javascript

I made a contact form for my website and I want to make validations. This is the HTML:

```
<form name="contact" method="post" action="Contact.php" onsubmit="return validateForm()" >
            <span class="formtext"> name:</span> <input id="nameinput" type="text" name="name" /><br />
            <span class="formtext"> email:</span> <input id="mailinput" type="text" name="email" /><br />
            <span class="formtext"> message:</span><br  /> <textarea id="messageinput" type="text" name="message"> </textarea> <br />
            <input id="submitinput" name="submit" type="submit" value="שלח"/>
        </form>
```

This is the JS:

```
// Contact Form //
function validateForm()
{
var x=document.forms["contact"]["name"].value;
var y=document.forms["contact"]["email"].value;
var atpos=y.indexOf("@");
var dotpos=y.lastIndexOf(".");
var z=document.forms["contact"]["email"].value;
if (x==null || x=="" || y==null || y=="" || z=="" || z==null)
  {
  alert("Please fill all the details");
  return false;
  }
  else
  if (atpos<1 || dotpos<atpos+2 || dotpos+2>=y.length)
  {
  alert ("Please fill a valid email address");
  return false;
  }
}
```

The problem has something to do with the variable 'z'. When I fill the form and send it, I get the "Please fill all the details" alert, even though I did fill the textarea. I know it's the 'z' because if I remove both the variable and the part inside the 'if' that has something to do with var 'z', the problem is solved- but then there is no validation.

Comment: You realize that `y` is the same as `z`, don't you?

Comment: Haha I wasted so much time on this. I'm so dumb..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The z also handles the `email` input instead of the `message` textarea

Try replacing

```
var z=document.forms["contact"]["email"].value;
```

by

```
var z=document.forms["contact"]["message"].value;
```